# SharePoint Hosted-App Site Content s Url

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I get the link to Site Contents for a SP Hosted-App Add-In?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Site Contents page(/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx) cannot be viewed in an add-in.

If you want to see all the contents of the add-in, like the lists, we can go to the link below to see it. And click the contents link, we can go to the list settings page.

```
https://tenant-xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SharePointHostedApp0103/_layouts/15/mcontent.aspx
```

[image]